# How to track down error when vitest doesn't give a line number?

Tags: reactjs, vite, vitest

I'm converting a React project from create-react-app and Jest to vite and vitest. Vite complains `Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.` and a error stack of vite methods, but no indication of where the alleged problem in my file is. (The file contains JSX, but has been changed to have a `.jsx` extension.)  My IDE (RubyMine) says there's no syntax error in the file.

How do I track down the code that's triggering this?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, in my case, the problem was a reference to `process.env.NODE_ENV` which needed to be replaced by a reference to `import.meta.env....`

I caught this when the file was incorporated in the app, and a runtime error was generated.